# phpspec, Doctrine: Testing that a parameter was set on an instantiated object

Tags: php, testing, doctrine-orm, phpspec

I'm trying to get started with PHPSpec and I've hit a wall. Things have gotten a bit convoluted in order to mock the proper things in the already-existing code I was given to work with, but in essence my question involves testing that something happened on an object which has just been created.

I have a `RepositoryFactory` that has `createRepository(EntityManager $em, $entityName)`

Doctrine's `EntityManager::getRepository($entityName)` just calls `RepositoryFactory::getRepository(EntityManager $em, $entityName)` and if the repository doesn't exist, THAT calls `RepositoryFactory::createRepository(EntityManager $em, $entityName)`

So, in my test, the repository is being mocked from `RepositoryFactory::getRepository`.

```
class MyEntityManagerSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(..., MyRepositoryFactory $rfact, MyEntityRepository $repo, ...)
    {
        ....

        $rfact->getRepository(Argument::any(), Argument::any())
              ->willReturn($repo);

        ...
    }

    function it_sets_a_field_on_repositories(MyEntityRepository $repo)
    {
        //This class calls its own getRepository, which calls 
        //getRepository on the factory, which ->willReturn($repo).
        //So, effectively (but without mocking the SUT) that means
        //$this->getRepository($entityName)->willReturn($repo)

        $entityName = 'blah\blah\FakeEntity';

        $repo->setField(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled(); 
        //The above fails with 
        //"No calls that match MyEntityRepository\P112->setField(*)"

        $gotRepo = $this->getRepository($entityName);

        $repo->setField(Argument::any())->shouldHaveBeenCalled();
        //This fails in the same way

        $gotRepo->shouldBe($repo);
        //This test passes but doesn't let me verify the property was set
        //and is therefore of little help to me

        $gotRepo->getField()->shouldNotBeNull();
        //I wanted to use shouldBe/shouldHaveBeenCalled but if the field's
        //been set that's just as good. Except this fails as well, with
        //"is_null(null) not expected to return true, but it did."
    }
```

Now before the answers start coming about testing in isolation, I realize that. I first started trying to write the check for the field-setting in `MyRepositoryFactory::createRepository` but the same sort of problem cropped up-- if I'm making the object within `createRepository`, then I have no mocks to test against with shouldBe/shouldHaveBeenCalled. But I'm trying to do things right, here, so if this is the wrong place for my test, I'd rather refactor a lot than have a hacky test that passes.

EDIT: This is the actual bit being tested

```
class MyEntityManager
{
    ...

    public function getRepository($entityName)
    {
        $repo = parent::getRepository($entityName);

        $metaData = $this->getClassMetadata($entityName);

        $flag = $this->getTarget() && $metaData->reflClass
            ->implementsInterface('Caj\Bundle\NameOfBundle\Model\NameOfBundleInterface');

        if($flag) {
            $repo->setField($this->getField());
        }
        return $repo;
    }
}
```

The $repo in the above bit is what should be being mocked here; `parent::getRepository` ==> `RepositoryFactory::getRepository` ==> `RepositoryFactory::createRepository`

Additionally, I know that the test gets into the `if($flag)` block, but the code inside isn't working. `$this->getField()` works and returns properly, but `$repo->setField` still receives null. `$repo->setField($field)` is a normal setter with no funky logic.

Comment: It's going to be a pain to test existing code with phpspec. Consider twice before you go this path. How does the code you're trying to test look like?

Comment: @JakubZalas Added the code you asked for.